# WPF datagrid inline editing

Tags: c#, wpfdatagrid, wpf-4.0

I have starting to work with WPF and C# to help designed a small app for my company.  The goal is to be able to look up a part number, display all possible matches in a grid view and finally be able to update the parts in the grid.  The data is being pull from a single table on a SQL table.

I have pulled most of my code from other examples and gotten it to work. However I am confused on the next steps in order to get editing to work.

Code is as follows:

XML CODE

```
<Window x:Class="SQLtests.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="387" Width="783">

<Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="Master" Margin="10,130,10,10" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True" IsTabStop="True" IsReadOnly="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
    <Button x:Name="Search" Content="Search"  Height="19" Margin="140,30,535,311" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="okSreach"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="PartNumber" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="19" Margin="10,30,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>

</Grid>
```

C# Code

```
namespace SQLtests
{

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void okSreach(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       string ConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;
       string CmdString = string.Empty;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConString))
        {
            CmdString = "SELECT PartsNumber, NewGMNumber, Interchange1 FROM Rydell.Master WHERE NewGMNumber = " + "'" + PartNumber.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(CmdString, con);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("Master");
            sda.Fill(dt);
            Master.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
        }
    }

}
}
```

Everything works fine as I am able to search for a part, however I have read some many different sources and ideas that getting inline editing to work is confusing.
I could be over my head too, as I am just starting out, any good books,websites, etc for C# and WPF is welcome

Comment: So you want to enter a number in your textbow and display all the matched Rows in your database, then edit the data you retrieved and save them into databbase

Comment: Correct that is currently what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use a ObservableCollection to bind instead of a datatable,
and I found in WPF,
it makes life a lot easier if you use a control like a ListView or even a ListBox,
where you have a lot more freedom to customize the control to your desire.

Be sure to use INotifyPropertyChanged, a basic sample would be like this.....

And what you would like to use with the listview would be a datatemplete or CellTemplte of the gridview.

Here is a example for you http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/datagrid-control/custom-columns/

^-^